# Scala implicit conversion from Array[T] to IndexedSeq[T]

Tags: arrays, scala, implicit-conversion

The following code wouldn't compile:

```
  implicit class indexedSeqWithBinarySearch[T](xs: IndexedSeq[T]) {
    def binarySearch(a: T) = ???
  }

  Array(0, 1, 2).binarySearch(1)
```

the method `binarySearch` is not added to the Array class. But I suppose that there's a implicit conversion chain from `Array[T] -> WrappedArray[T] -> mutable.IndexedSeq[T] -> collection.IndexedSeq[T]` ? How can I make an `Array` an `IndexedSeq`?

Comment: One option is to define a conversion from the specific collection types you're using; this way you're also not relying on inheritence (i.e. subtype polymorphism).

Comment: Yes, but why can't `Array`s be converted to `IndexedSeq`s?

Comment: It can, but `x: X` in a call signature means that `x` must be an instance of an actual subtype of `X`, not just convertible to `X`; see my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is not a subtype of `IndexedSeq` but your implicit class definition would necessitate for that to be the case. Instead, you need it to take any type that is *viewable as* `IndexedSeq[T]`.

I'm using `myTail` as a more realistic example here:

```
implicit class indexedSeqWithBinarySearch[T, LS <% IndexedSeq[T]](xs: LS) {
  def myTail = {
    val xs1 = xs: IndexedSeq[T] // now the cast works
    xs1.tail
  }
}

println(Array(1, 2, 3).myTail)
```

The cast `xs: IndexedSeq[T]` works because of that `LS <% IndexedSeq[T]` view bound in the signature.

`A <% B` specifies that `A` must be viewable as `B`, so there needs to be a conversion from `A` to `B` within scope at the call site, and this conversion be in effect in the method body.

---

Update: without the about-to-be-deprecated view bounds, the implicit class declaration would look like:

```
implicit class indexedSeqWithBinarySearch[T, LS](xs: LS)(implicit ls2ixseq: LS => IndexedSeq[T]) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: note that `<%` will be deprecated. http://jatinpuri.com/2014/03/replace-view-bounds/

Comment: that's great to know :) I'll update the answer at some point.