# Why does Scala compiler think there is a polymorphic type error?

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism

My code is simple:

```
class MyClass {
  var foo: IndexedSeq[MyClass] = IndexedSeq()
  def bar(newValues: MyClass*) = foo = newValues.toArray
}
```

The class contains a variable and a method. The variable `foo` is an `IndexSeq` of `MyClass` objects. It also contains a method `bar` which takes as parameters a `Seq` of `MyClass` objects. Because a `Seq[T]` cannot be assigned to a `IndexSeq[T]`, since the latter is a subclass of the former, I had to call `toArray`.

With this code, the compiler complains as follows

```
polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [B >: MyClass]Array[B]
 required: IndexedSeq[MyClass]
  def bar(newValues: MyClass*) = foo = newValues.toArray
                                                 ^
```

So I found a solution, which is to call `toIndexSeq` instead of `toArray`, and the compiler does not complain anymore.

Even though the problem is gone for me, I still wonder why there was such an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala implicit conversion from Array\[T\] to IndexedSeq\[T\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704028/scala-implicit-conversion-from-arrayt-to-indexedseqt)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [spec for `Array`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Array), you'll notice that it does not extend `Seq` or `IndexedSeq`.  In fact, `Array` is pretty a bare-bones class that extends only `Serializable` and `Cloneable`, because it is based on the Java `Array` implementation.  You're probably used to treating it like a `Seq` because of the implicit conversions available on `Array`, in [`ArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps@inheritance-diagram).

The problem is that there is no implicit conversion from `Array[B >: MyClass]` (which is what is returned by `toArray`) to `IndexedSeq[MyClass]`.  If you explicitly provide the generic parameter of `toArray` or use type ascription, this problem is solved, because there is an implicit conversion from `Array[MyClass]` to `Seq[MyClass]`:

```
def bar(newValues: MyClass*) = foo = newValues.toArray[MyClass]
def bar(newValues: MyClass*) = foo = (newValues.toArray : Array[MyClass])
```

This even simpler example might help elucidate:

```
class Foo
Seq(new Foo).toArray : Seq[Foo] //fails
Seq(new Foo).toArray[Foo] : Seq[Foo] //works!
(Seq(new Foo).toList.toArray : Array[Foo]) : Seq[Foo] //also works!
```

Comment: Does `toArray` return a different `Array` than the one in [this diagram](http://docs.scala-lang.org/resources/images/collections.immutable.png)?

Comment: No, I guess those arrows with dotted lines mean that `Array` and `String` can be implicitly converted to `IndexedSeq`.

Comment: Yes -- dotted arrows mean an implicit conversion is present in `Predef`, and the bold lines represent the default type returned by methods that instantiate the traits.  For example, `Seq()` returns a `List()` (which is a `LinearSeq`), and `IndexedSeq` returns a `Vector`.